# org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException

Tags: spring-boot, avro, spring-kafka

Using Avro message format.

Getting Below Exception. It is not able to map to AvroPlanCompleteTrigger java object after de-serilization. Can someone please help?

> Bean [com.wom.repl.odr.receiver.Receiver@606b1c65]; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Cannot handle message; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Cannot convert from [com.wom.repl.odr.dto.AvroPlanCompleteTrigger] to [com.wom.repl.odr.dto.AvroPlanCompleteTrigger] for GenericMessage [payload={"groupId": 609001, "runUUID": "runuuid", "wmtItemNumber": "123456", "sourceLocation": 987, "retryCount": 3, "applicationName": "Jenkins"}, headers={kafka_offset=0, kafka_receivedMessageKey=null, kafka_receivedPartitionId=0, kafka_receivedTopic=test3, kafka_acknowledgment=Acknowledgment for ConsumerRecord(topic = test3, partition = 0, offset = 0, CreateTime = 1574768943315, checksum = 2886880703, serialized key size = -1, serialized value size = 29, key = null, value = {"groupId": 1234, "runUUID": "runuuid", "wmtItemNumber": "123456", "sourceLocation": 987, "retryCount": 3, "applicationName": "Jenkins"})}], failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload={"groupId": 1234, "runUUID": "runuuid", "wmtItemNumber": "123456", "sourceLocation": 987, "retryCount": 3, "applicationName": "Jenkins"}, headers={kafka_offset=0, kafka_receivedMessageKey=null, kafka_receivedPartitionId=0, kafka_receivedTopic=test3, kafka_acknowledgment=Acknowledgment for ConsumerRecord(topic = test3, partition = 0, offset = 0, CreateTime = 1574768943315, checksum = 2886880703, serialized key size = -1, serialized value size = 29, key = null, value = {"groupId": 609001, "runUUID": "runuuid", "wmtItemNumber": "123456", "sourceLocation": 987, "retryCount": 3, "applicationName": "Jenkins"})}],    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:178),  at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:72),   at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:47),   at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:794),  at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:738),    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.access$2200(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:245),   at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer$ListenerInvoker.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1031),  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511),     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266),    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)]  :END

Pom dependencies version:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
            <artifactId>avro</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

AvroDeserializer method below which I am using to get AvroPlanCompleteTrigger this java object.

```
    public T deserialize(String topic, byte[] data) {
        try {
            T result = null;

            if (data != null) {
                LOGGER.debug("data='{}'", DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(data));

                DatumReader<GenericRecord> datumReader = new SpecificDatumReader<>(
                        targetType.newInstance().getSchema());
                Decoder decoder = DecoderFactory.get().binaryDecoder(data, null);

                result = (T) datumReader.read(null, decoder);
                LOGGER.debug("deserialized data='{}'", result);
            }
            return result;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new SerializationException(
                    "Can't deserialize data '" + Arrays.toString(data) + "' from topic '" + topic + "'", ex);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have deserialized a `com.wom.replenishment.odr.dto.AvroPlanCompleteTrigger` but the method parameter is a `com.wom.repl.odr.dto.AvroPlanCompleteTrigger`.

Spring doesn't know how to convert from one to the other.

Comment: Yes Gary. How to resolve this? Serialized and deserialized objects are same.

Comment: You edited the question; I have rejected your edit to my answer to make it conform with your edit. In the original question, the third package element is different `replenishment` Vs. `repl`. The classes might be the same "shape" but they are not the same class. Before the edit to your question, to error was clear. If your original question was wrong somehow and your new question is correct; then it could be a class loader problem.

Comment: Seems strange that your original question was a copy/paste of an exception which you later edited. If indeed the classes are identical then it it most likely a ClassLoader problem.

Comment: Any way to fix this? AvroPlanCompleteTrigger class is same for quite sure about that.

Comment: You need to figure out why Kafka is using a different classloader; one solution might be to create the deserializer and inject it into the `DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory` using one of the alternate constructors; that way you can be sure the same classloader is used to create the deserializer and listener.

Comment: That is how it is right now.

return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs(), new StringDeserializer(), new AvroDeserializer<>(AvroPlanCompleteTrigger.class));

Comment: Then what you are seeing makes no sense if they are truly the same class; you will need to use a debugger to figure out what's happening.

Comment: org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.support.PayloadArgumentResolver in this class fromMessage(message, targetClass, parameter); this method is returning NULL. That's what I got from debugging.

Comment: This issue got resolved. It was eclipse issue. When I tried to run project from terminal it worked.